# Why does a liter water contain more information than all the information on the whole internet?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, information

[image]

In this (probably well known) picture you can see that a litre water contains much more information than all the information on the whole internet. Now I understand that the total number of possible arrangements of all the water molecules (considered as basic units; if we consider the structure of the molecules the information is even greater, and it will become maximal if we consider all the elementary particles in it), due to the enormous amount of molecules (n), is bigger than the number of possible arrangements of ones and zeros on the net (for the internet n becomes the number of ones and zeros).

This is because the information content of water (or the internet) is

$ I={log}_2 {N(=2^n)} $, and the related thermodynamic entropy (only for water)

$ S=k_B{log_2} N$,

But somehow I think you can find more (useful) information on the internet. Is there a subjective element for the information content that's bigger for the internet than that of water, which has to do with structure and the way we interpret that structure, assigning meaning to it?

Of course, the information content of the internet is much bigger than the content of a litre water if we take all the hardware in consideration where the information is stored on.

Comment: That is, at best, a misleading comparison between configuration entropy and 'information' that you can get at and use.

Comment: This doesn't compare the utility of the information.  Having a hard drive full of random characters is still more information than that same hard drive half-full of useful programs.  The amount of information does not measure it's utility.

Comment: @JMac-That I understand. So the information content can be very high, while at the same time that information has little utility (like the information in the litre water)?

Comment: This question shows the same misintepretation of "information" as measured by entropy as all your other questions on the topic: The information measured by entropy simply is not the same as what humans colloquially call "information". No human would call a totally uniformly random sequence "informative", yet its expected entropy is very high.

Answer (score 3):

This is a chart of **information capacity** compared to size.

We have no method of storing information in the thermodynamic entropy of water.  There is a lot of information capacity in the system; it doesn't mean we can actually use it.

They are comparing it to the "information" on the internet stored as bits.  Each of these bits can be deliberately changed and read; this is why it holds much more information to humans.  The same reason you would say the words of a book hold more information than a leaf.

The two types of information don't really compare; that is the confusion.

Comment: @JMac- Got it!So if we could store information in every elementary particle (one bit per elementary particle) in the litre of water, we could store more information in it than on the whole internet? But then again, if we could store information in the total *mass* of the internet (again in the elementary particles out of which it's built), the two information capacities per unit volume would be about the same order. There is more information *capacity* in a litre water but on the internet, there is more information stored (*in formation*) that's useful for humans and in a much bigger volume.